# When can we use FORK_URL as Alchemy API key during foundry test?

Tags: foundry

When can we use FORK_URL as Alchemy API key during foundry test? I am trying to learn how to use foundry, but seems like a youtuber is using FORK_URL as Alchemy API key. Is FORK_URL depends on a mainnet or testnet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your app in Alchemy; if it's on mainnet - you can use it on mainnet, if it's on Sepolia - you can use it on Sepolia.

`--fork-url` just gives you an option to "live" testing your code on **a** network, rather than locally on your machine.

You can read more about it in [Foundry's Docs](https://book.getfoundry.sh/forge/fork-testing?highlight=fork#forking-mode).